# Connecting to database with JDBC URL

Tags: java, database, jdbc, connect

My requirement is to check can we connect to a database with no schema defined through a java program and create a database.
this works fine

```
Connection  connection =
           DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://wcspocca-db.cloudapp.net:50001/db2inst1","vmadmin","password@123;");
```

database: db2
schema: db2inst1

but

```
Connection  connection =
           DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://wcspocca-db.cloudapp.net:50001/","vmadmin","password@123;");
```

fails
WHY?

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mo: [jcc][10165][10045][4.7.85] Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://wcspocca-db.cloudapp.net:50001/. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

Comment: so DBName is compulsory. thanks.

Comment: Can we achieve the below through java program
1. connect to a remote database db2 installed on a host machine 
2. create a database schema "PROD" on the database db2
3. execute some table creation sqls

machine 1: wcspocca-db.cloudapp.net. (db2 installed without any database schema created)
machine 2: (running java program. to connect to database installed in the above remote machine to run some sqls)

Answer (score 1):

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://wcspocca-db.cloudapp.net:50001/!!DBNAME!!","vmadmin","password@123;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second example the database is not specified. You can find the requirements in the [DB2 JDBC documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.java/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052342.dita):

```
>>-+-jdbc:db2:------+--//--server--+---------+--/--database----->
   +-jdbc:db2j:net:-+              '-:--port-'
   '-jdbc:ids:------'

>--+---------------------------+-------------------------------\><
   '-:--| connection-options |-'
```

The database parameter is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

How I usually connect to a database using jave is like the following: *Spacing it out to allow you to read the text below*

```
//Wide Scope Variables
static Connection conn = null; //right now this connection is off
static String dbURL = "database url"; //I use SQL developer and your able to grab the connection url there

static String user = "This can be empty and ask user for input of hard code the user name";

static String pass = "same as above";
```

In the method where you want to check the driver and connection I usually do it like this

```
//Register the Driver
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");   
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    //Set up connection
    try
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,user,password);
        conn.clearWarnings();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The first **try catch** code registers the driver to the SQL developer then the second **try catch** sets up the connection to the database. This helped save me a lot of head aches and I find it the most Direct route when using java.

Answer (score 0):

check the url carefully, after the port number if you do not put database name which you want to connect then how it will connect. Its like you are giving a home address whitout the plot number.